# Automate plotting of different figures in R

Tags: r

I want to make function that loops through a dataframe to plots different plot figures next to each using par(), one plot is bar plot, second is scatter plot and the last is box plot, my data frame:

```
structure(list(rated = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), turns = c(13L, 
16L, 61L, 61L), victory_status = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("mate", 
"outoftime", "resign"), class = "factor"), winner = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("charcoal", "cream"), class = "factor"), 
    increment_code = structure(c(1L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("15+2", 
    "20+0", "5+10"), class = "factor"), cream_rating = c(1500L, 
    1322L, 1496L, 1439L), charcoal_rating = c(1191L, 1261L, 1500L, 
    1454L), opening_name = structure(c(4L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("King's Pawn Game: Leonardis Variation", 
    "Nimzowitsch Defense: Kennedy Variation", "Queen's Pawn Game: Zukertort Variation", 
    "Slav Defense: Exchange Variation"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried:

```
par(mai=rep(0.5, 4))
layout(matrix(c(1,1, 2,2, 0, 3,3, 0), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE))
chess_games<-read.csv("./data/games.csv")
chess_games_rated<-table(chess_games$rated)
head (chess_games_rated)
barplot(chess_games_rated, cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.2, font=1)


chess_games<-read.csv("./data/games.csv")
chess_games_rated<-table(chess_games$winner, chess_games$rated)
barplot(chess_games_rated, col=c("blue","red","green"), cex.axis=1.5)
legend(x="topleft", legend = levels(chess_games$winner), col=c("blue","red","green"), pch=19, cex=1, pt.cex = 1)

boxplot.1<-boxplot(cream_rating ~ victory_status, chess_games[!chess_games$winner %in% "draw", ], cex.axis=1.2)
```

Can I assign the above code into a function?

Comment: *"I'm getting an error"*. Please include the verbatim text of the error, there are too many to guess, and it can be informative to looking at the code.

Comment: On simple reading, though, this code is strewn with logic errors. `if (y=chess)` is wrong, you likely mean `==`, otherwise it's completely missing the point.

Comment: `(for c(x,y,z) in chess_games)` is not valid R syntax.

Comment: adding on r2evans remarks you're using multiple else statements within each of them is an if statement

Comment: @r2evans I apologize for the inconvenience, I updated the question, I appreciate your help, I also did update = with ==, what is the right syntax, I was looking for a function that will be fn(x,y,z) where fn is function that loops through the data frame, x is bar plot, y is scatter plot and z is boxplot, and use par() within the function to arrange them next to each other in a row.

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk I do hold high regards to r2evan for the support and help and certainly the knowledge and the experience, I know my coding skills are primitive, but everythime I ask question here I learn alot from experts like r2evan, they give the right syntax and points where I did wrong so I can avoid the same mistake in the future.

Comment: I cannot imagine (and I'm trying!) what you are intending to do with all of this: you read in your file twice, with no apparent need; `for c(x,y,z)` is still a mystery; you plot twice and *then* change the `layout`, so either you're giving us some useless code, or you think that base R will let you add previous plots to the current `layout` (won't work this way). Perhaps it would help to explain what plot you want in the end, specifically which observations in which plot.

Comment: @r2evans I'm trying to end with three different plot (scatter, bar and box) next to each other, I was trying generate the plots to see how they look separately, then I wanted to loop them to show them next to each other, the last step is to assign the loop to a function where I can call and enter the the 3 inputs (to pull for me the plots) but it did not work. You can ignore the first three plots code, and focus on how to loop three different plots in a dataframe.

Comment: @r2evans I did not mean to distract you with my code, I'm beginner and I'm still learning.

Comment: @r2evans I updated my question with the code and the question in the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal translation of your three manual plots into a function looks like below.

```r
myfunc <- function(data) {
  stopifnot(
    all(c("rated", "winner", "cream_rating", "victory_status") %in% names(data))
  )

  layout(matrix(c(1,1, 2,2, 0, 3,3, 0), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE))

  rated <- xtabs(~ rated, data = data)
  br1 <- barplot(rated, cex.lab = 1.5, cex.axis = 1.2, font = 1)

  winner_rated <- xtabs(~ winner + rated, data = data)
  br2 <- barplot(winner_rated, col = c("blue","red","green"), cex.axis = 1.5)
  legend(x = "topleft", legend = levels(data$winner),
         col = c("blue","red","green"), pch = 19, cex = 1, pt.cex = 1)

  bx3 <- boxplot(cream_rating ~ victory_status, data = data[!data$winner %in% "draw", ],
                 cex.axis = 1.2)
  invisible(list(br1, br2, bx3))
}

myfunc(chess_games)
```

[image: sample 3-way plot]

It does *not* check that `data$winner` is a `factor`, nor if the number of unique `levels` is other than length 3.

It does invisibly return a `list` with the return value of each of the three plots. While it seems uninspiring for the `barplot`s, it is still somewhat informative if you want/need it elsewhere. The `boxplot` contains significantly more information if you need it.

```r
ret <- myfunc(chess_games)
str(ret)
# List of 3
#  $ : num [1:2, 1] 0.7 1.9
#  $ : num [1:2] 0.7 1.9
#  $ :List of 6
#   ..$ stats: 'integer' num [1:5, 1:4] NA NA NA NA NA ...
#   ..$ n    : num [1:4] 0 3 1 1
#   ..$ conf : num [1:2, 1:4] NA NA 1458 1534 1500 ...
#   ..$ out  : num(0) 
#   ..$ group: num(0) 
#   ..$ names: chr [1:4] "draw" "mate" "outoftime" "resign"
```

It is not *general*, in that it won't work with customizations or slightly-different data. Doing so would be rather difficult, since you're using different customization for each plot. Because of this, I start with `stopifnot` which will complain (and fail) if all of the required columns are not found.

If you need this to be more dynamic (variable number of plots or different variables to run `table` (or `xtabs`) on, then this is certainly feasible but you will need to lose per-plot customization.

---

Data. I removed the last column since you weren't using it and it was not parsing with this simple `read.table`.

```r
chess_games <- read.table(header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE, text="
   rated   turns   victory_status  winner  increment_code  cream_rating    charcoal_rating
   FALSE   13     outoftime       cream    15+2             1500           1191
   TRUE    16      resign        charcoal  5+10             1322           1261
   TRUE    61      mate           cream    5+10             1496           1500
   TRUE    61      mate           cream    20+0            1439            1454
   TRUE    95      mate           cream    30+3            1523            1469
   FALSE   5       draw            draw    10+0            1250            1002            ")
```

Comment: That's amazing!, I appreciate your support, now I have to study how you did it, every question that you answer I learn something new, by the way, is it possible to place the plot next to each other?

Comment: *"place the plot next to each other"* is confusing in the context that you provided the call to `layout` that puts the three plots together. If you want multiple calls to `myfunc` to be placed side-by-side, then ... No, and frankly if it were trivial then I would likely recommend against it, as that will make the presentation of your data difficult to do well at scale. Consider handling side-by-side plots in whatever report-generation tool you're using, whether LaTeX/pdf or rmarkdown/sweave or HTML.

Comment: I totally agree, @r2evans, I tried this line`par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
nf <- layout(matrix(c(1,2,3),nrow=1), widths=c(2,2,2), heights=c(2,1,1), TRUE) ` and the figures looks small and hard to read eventhough they are next to each other, I tried to make them larger, but it doesn't work. I downloaded laTeX, but I never learned to use it, I thought learning R will overcome these things, but it seems it is not.

Comment: I updated the dataset, is this helpful in replicating dataset? @r2evans

Comment: Underneath the hood, I believe `par(mfrow)` is using `layout`, and you cannot "nest" `layout`s, so use one or the other, not both. Try *just* `par(mfrow=c(1,3))` in place of the `layout` call.